# Are there properties of polynomials reflected in the Asymptotic distribution of their zeros?

Tags: polynomials

There are many results of the form :

"Here is an interesting family of polynomials of a complex variable and here is the asymptotic distribution of zeros."

Such results can be found for The Jones polynomials of families of Links a la [Shrock and Chang](http://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0103043)

There are results on the zeros of Partition polynomials by [Boyer and Goh](http://www.math.drexel.edu/~rboyer/papers/partitions_experimental.pdf)

Alan Sokal also has many papers investigating of limiting behavior of zeros when looking at Potts Model partition functions.

I am wondering if there are any result that go the other direction?

In particular I have a family of recursively defined polynomials and I know that the zeros converge on the unit circle and a collection of isolated points.

Has anyone seen results that would tell me something about such polynomials, or any results at all that start with a family of polynomials and their limiting distribution of zeros?

P.S.

I don't really know what a good tag should be. So if anyone knows please add it.